# Using An Ember Component in a list

Tags: ember.js, ember-router, ember-components

I am using an Ember Component(Eg: a button) in an array:

```
{{#each employees as |employee|}}
   {{employee.first_name}}
   {{component "button" action='promoteEmployee' emp_id=employee.id}}
{{/each}}
```

And, in component action on button is pressButton(eg):

```
pressButton: function(){
  this.sendAction('action', this.get('emp_id'));
}
```

But, when the list of employee  gets rendered(eg):

Alice |Promote|
Mark  |Promote|
Tesla |Promote|

And i click on the button to promote an employee(say employee Mark), the emp_id which is bubbled up is of Alice(always of the first employee in the list) (and not Mark), can you let me know where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You have component named button? Why do you use such weird syntax for component declaration in template?

Comment: You are missing quotes on `emp_id`, should it be `this.get('emp_id'))`?.

Comment: @carcel , yes that was a typo. `Edited` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to pass the employee id as a parameter of the action:

Template:

```
{{#each employees as |employee|}}
    {{employee.first_name}}
    {{button action=(action 'promoteEmployee' employee.id)}}
{{/each}}
```

Component:

```
actions: {
  pressButton(empId){
    this.get('action')(empId);
  }
}
```